# How can I change this CSS for desktop browsers only?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I would like to change the following piece of css:

```
ul.deals > li > a > img {
border-radius: 5px;
border-width: 0;
min-height: 200px;
width: 100%;
}
```

This is CSS which is perfect for mobile devices - the image nicely fills the width of the screen. However when viewed on a desktop browser the image grows to the window width - as per the css requests - but this looks awful as the image is very very stretched.

How can I tell the above css to only apply to mobile devices - and allow me to write a bit of css specific to wider sized devices?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im pretty sure you need [Media Queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/CSS/Media_queries) here

for example

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {
  ul.deals > li > a > img {
  border-radius: 5px;
  border-width: 0;
  min-height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
 }
}
```